# NavDropdown overflowing the screen

Tags: css, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a Dropdown menu at the right edge of `react-bootstrap`'s Navbar:

```
<Nav className="container-fluid justify-content-end">
  <NavDropdown alignRight title="Dropdown" flip>
    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/1">Apply Coupon</NavDropdown.Item>
    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/2">Change Password</NavDropdown.Item>
    <NavDropdown.Divider />
    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/4">Logout</NavDropdown.Item>
  </NavDropdown>
</Nav>
```

Despite what is suggested in the best answer [here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/4149) (i.e. using `alignRight` and `flip`), the items in my menu overflow:

[image]

I am using `bootstrap` 5.1.1 and `react-bootstrap` 1.6.3.
How do I fix this?

**UPDATE:** It works fine [in the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/the-overflow-example-cer9p?file=/src/App.js), but overflows in all the browsers that I tried (Opera, Chrome, Firefox). I have submitted [an issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/6028). In the meanwhile, I will appreciate a temporary workaround.

Comment: I opened your example directly (https://cer9p.csb.app/) and it looks ok. No overflowing issues.

Comment: @JiříVítek Yes, I know. It seems to be running in the sandbox even when opened in a separate window. Please try to actually run it using the react server to see the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not on my workstation atm. I can simulate your issue in the sandbox by removing "right: 0" from "dropdown-menu-right". So you can check if right: 0 gets applied (together with position absolute and position relative on the parent) when you open your example in the browser directly.

Comment: @JiříVítek You are right! The `dropdown-menu-right` class is not shown at all . I added `right:0` in it and that solved the problem. So, should I add a class with `right:0` to my NavDropdown or there is a better solution?

Comment: I am not using bootstrap so I am not sure what is the cause of this issue. You can double check if you have the same version of bootstrap in your project as is used in the sandbox (there might be a little mismatch). You can always create a custom class or use inline css to make sure dropdowns stays the same even if you update the bootstrap version. Frankly I dont know what would be the best way to go since I never use css frameworks.

Comment: @JiříVítek That `right:0` is lost no matter what I do. I tried both adding a class to `NavDropdown` and adding a `<div>` after it (i.e. surrounding all the menu items). Am I missing the correct way of doing it in CSS?

Comment: There might be a different rule in your/bootstrap css that overrides it. You would need to check using developer tools and find out what rules are applied to the element and get the exact file and line number. Also be aware the CSS can be cached so even if you make a change to css file, save it and refresh the page you might still end up with old version.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. Property `align` fixed the alignment.

For example, `<NavDropdown align="end" title="Alignment">...</NavDoropdown>`

I am using react-bootstrap 2.1.1 and Bootstrap 5.1.3

Answer (score 1):

Based on the insight of @JiříVítek, my solution for now is to import my `styles.css` before importing `react-bootstrap`, with the following:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Also need "left: auto", but align="end" is the right solution.